# How do I flip one of my loops of current to be in the other direction?

Tags: plotting, physics, vector

I'm new to Mathematica and I have two loops of current that are both going in the same direction, but I want to flip them so that they go in opposite directions... I can't figure out where I'm going wrong?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Q = 1;
Ν = 100;
μo = 1;
R0 = 5;
r = {x, y, z};
r0 = {R0 Cos[(2 π)/Ν i], 0, 
   R0 Sin[(2 π)/Ν i]};
I0 = 1;
dl = {-((2 π)/Ν) Sin[(2 π)/Ν i], 
   0, (2 π)/Ν Cos[(2 π)/Ν i]};
rp = {xp[t], yp[t], zp[t]};
Βp = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 0\), \(Ν - 1\)]\ \(
\*FractionBox[\(\(\ \)\(\(μo\)\(\ \)\(I0\)\(\ \)\)\), \(\(4\)\(\ \
\)\(π\)\(\ \)\)] {
\*FractionBox[\(\((dl\[Cross]\((rp - r0)\))\)[\([\)\(1\)\(]\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Norm[rp - r0]\), \(3\)]], 
\*FractionBox[\(\((dl\[Cross]\((rp - r0)\))\)[\([\)\(2\)\(]\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Norm[rp - r0]\), \(3\)]], 
\*FractionBox[\(\((dl\[Cross]\((rp - r0)\))\)[\([\)\(3\)\(]\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Norm[rp - r0]\), \(3\)]]}\)\);
v = {xp'[t], yp'[t], zp'[t]};
Ϝ = q v\[Cross]Βp;
m = 1;
q = 10;
{xp, yp, zp} = NDSolveValue[
  {m xp''[t] == Ϝ [[1]], xp'[0] == .1, xp[0] == 2,
   m yp''[t] == Ϝ [[2]], yp'[0] == 0, yp[0] == 3,
   m zp''[t] == Ϝ [[3]], zp'[0] == 0, zp[0] == 0},
  {xp, yp, zp}, {t, 0, 200}]

z = 0;
Β1 = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 0\), \(Ν - 1\)]\ \(
\*FractionBox[\(\(\ \)\(\(μo\)\(\ \)\(I0\)\(\ \)\)\), \(\(4\)\(\ \
\)\(π\)\(\ \)\)] {
\*FractionBox[\(\((dl\[Cross]\((r - r0)\))\)[\([\)\(1\)\(]\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Norm[r - r0]\), \(3\)]], 
\*FractionBox[\(\((dl\[Cross]\((r - r0)\))\)[\([\)\(2\)\(]\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Norm[r - r0]\), \(3\)]]}\)\);
VectorPlot[Β1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 VectorPoints -> 24, StreamPoints -> Medium, 
 StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

This gives me if the currents are flowing the same way. I know that it works, but every time I mess with the VectorPlot it doesn't look how it's supposed to with the magnetic field lines of one of the two loops flowing in the opposite direction.

Comment: Oops, edited it now. I forgot to add it initially

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Still making a lot of mistakes, clearly.

Comment: Another comment is, you `NDSolveValue` for `{xp,yp,zp}`, but do you use these variables in the `VectorPlot`?

Comment: No, they're from a VectorPlot3D / ParametricPlot3D that I WAS able to figure out and just didn't include when asking about this. They belong with that, and I forgot to take it out when posting!

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! hmmm...I might be misunderstanding, but there seems to be only one loop here, given by `dl` and `r0`? should there be two (or should I be understanding it differently)?

Comment: With your code I do get two loops flowing in opposite directions (https://imgur.com/a/oyISCTg) - or did you mean something different?